# Java: cannot find symbol class Product_ even invalidating cache and rebuilding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, class, intellij-idea

In a Java (Spring Boot app), I created a new branch and make my changes. Then, I tried to debug the project and got `java: cannot find symbol class Product_` for lots of classes. There are only 3-5 classes belonging to my changes, but most of them are irrelevant to my changes.

In IntelliJ IDEA, I tried several workarounds e.g. invalidating cache and rebuilding project, restarting IntelliJ, but cannot solve it.
I also created a new branch and tried to run it before applying my changes, and it is working. The problem is completely related to volatile (underscore classes).

So, how can I fix that?

Comment: @Editor Any reply please instead of edit?

Comment: Can the project be built from gradle/maven command line? It is needed to distinguish IDE error and project's error

Comment: Did you try to _debug_ that project before? Or just run? And if you switch do the previous branch, does debugging work there?

Comment: What is the output of ’mvn clean install’ ?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov `mvn clean install -DskipTests` seems to work properly.

Comment: @cyberbrain Yes, I also tried to debug. But there are also lots of errors for the same classes. It cannot create metadata classes.

Comment: Did you open this in IDEA as a maven project at all? Or just as a regular Java project?

Comment: I opened as always I was opening via Open menu. There is no problem regarding to the project, but anyhow, IntelliJ changed the SDK and that was the problem I think. After changing it to Java 11 and making some rebuild, invalidate cache, the problem seems to be solved now. Thanks a lot to all of you for your helps. Regards.